# Android API call to determine user setting "Data Enabled"

Tags: android, android-wireless

My program tries to detect whether a mobile network is available at a certain location.

The issue is that when I don't have a data connection it doesn't mean the network is not there... it depends on the user preferences.
There are APIs available for `NetworkInfo.isAvailable()`, and for user settings such as whether user is roaming and roaming is enabled or whether AirplaneMode is on.

My problem is that I can't figure out whether the user has data services disabled under Settings/WirelessNetworks/MobileNetworks.

Sounds like a trivial problem but I haven't found an API call.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your activity:

```
boolean mobileDataAllowed = Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), "mobile_data", 1) == 1;
```

Source: https://github.com/yanchenko/quick-settings/blob/master/src/com/bwx/bequick/handlers/MobileDataSettingHandler2.java#L123

Comment: Where can I find a list of all of the strings you can pass (i.e. "mobile_data") to Setttings.Secure?

Comment: Officially, [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html).  For the undocumented or hidden settings, you need to view the source of core/java/android/provider/Settings.java, which you can view [here](http://omapzoom.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/provider/Settings.java;hb=HEAD).

Comment: Hi, is there a way to recieve some notification for change of settings , and only then read "mobile_data" ?

Comment: @ransh I'm not sure. It'd probably be best to ask this as a separate question anyway.

Comment: @bmaupin it gives me false when im receiving notification for wifi disabled but my mobile data button has been enabled y is it still working lik u mentioned??

Answer (score 1):

I know above answer worked for OP. But in few devices I found it returns true even if data is disabled.
So I found one alternate solution which is in Android API.

[getDataState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDataState()) method of [TelephonyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) will be very useful.

Below function returns false when cellular data is disabled otherwise true.

```
private boolean checkMobileDataIsEnabled(Context context){
        boolean mobileYN = false;

        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (tm.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY) {
            TelephonyManager tel = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
//          if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
//          {
//              mobileYN = Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), "mobile_data", 0) == 1;
//          }
//          else{
//              mobileYN = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), "mobile_data", 0) == 1;
//          }
            int dataState = tel.getDataState();
            Log.v(TAG,"tel.getDataState() : "+ dataState);
            if(dataState != TelephonyManager.DATA_DISCONNECTED){
                mobileYN = true;
            }

        }

        return mobileYN;
    }
```

Comment: it doesnt give excat result when you are recieving notification for wifi disabled..

Comment: it return false even when mobiledata is enabled

Comment: well, it works for me for all the devices. Interestingly, for the device you have not working. try other answers in that case. which device you have ?

Comment: @ Mohammadhussain Khatri i have redmi3s prime