# How can I monitor for changes to mobile data being enabled on Android?

Tags: java, android

I have successfully used the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806709/android-how-to-tell-if-mobile-network-data-is-enabled-or-disabled-even-when) to perform a one off check if mobile data is enabled, but I would like to receive a notification of such change, for example when a user goes to this screen:

[image: Mobile Data Enable screen]

Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe you can use SettingsContentObserver like described in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896746/android-is-there-a-broadcast-action-for-volume-changes

Comment: Good thinking, but I followed your idea and found ways to detect changes in on/off of bluetooth, airplane mode, GPRS, all sorts but *not* mobile data :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OnNetworkActiveListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.OnNetworkActiveListener.html#onNetworkActive%28%29) to monitor activation of network data. The [ConnectivityManager class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getActiveNetworkInfo%28%29) can give you infos on the currently active network connection. It would go like this :

```
ConnectivityManager cm = getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfos networkInfos = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

if(networkInfos.isConnected()){
    //Do something
} else {
    //Do something else
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This looks like it will work so I've up voted it but I actually need < API 21

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isNetworkOn(Context context, int networkType) {
        final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            final Network[] networks = connectivityManager.getAllNetworks();
            for (Network network : networks) {
                final NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(network);
                if (networkInfo.getType() == networkType && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") final NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(networkType);
            if (networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```