# Toggle mobile data with java android

Tags: java, android, toggle

I want to toggle the the mobile data button that can be seen when you pull down the menu strip. I have tried a couple of examples, but none seem to work. ([How to disable Mobile Data on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644144/how-to-disable-mobile-data-on-android) as an example). Is this simply not possible and if it is not possible, how would I go about disabling all connections?

Comment: Are you asking - How to add a toggle, when its in "On" state the internet is enabled, when its "OFF" state the internet should be disabled.

Comment: I want to disable the 3g/4g connection. The purpose I had in mind was to disable all connections on the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you might check the status of mobile data and consequently enabling or disabling them.

To check the status see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806709/how-to-tell-if-mobile-network-data-is-enabled-or-disabled-even-when-connected) answer and to toggle the data see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644144/how-to-disable-mobile-data-on-android/8962211#8962211).

Remember to add to the manifest all permissions and keep in mind that this method is no longer available on android 5 (Lollipop).

Comment: I take it that there is know way to toggle mobile data on and off on Lollipop?

Comment: You can toggle mobile data on Lollipop  only if you have root permissions