# How to know programmatically whether MobileData is enabled on Android P?

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

Is there a way to check programmatically whether MobileData is enabled on Android P?

Before P, we can use `getMobileDataEnabled()` with reflection like this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12864897/3752013

But after P, reflection methods throw exception... 
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces#results-of-keeping-non-sdk

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following class

```
public class NetworkEventReceiver extends ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback {
private final NetworkRequest networkRequest;
private final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
private final Context context;


public NetworkEventReceiver(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    networkRequest = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
            .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
            .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
            .build();
}

public void enable() {
    connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onAvailable(Network network) {
    executeActions(network);
    super.onAvailable(network);
}

@Override
public void onLost(Network network) {
    executeActions(network);
    super.onLost(network);
}

private void executeActions(Network network) {
    try {
        NetworkCapabilities info = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network);

        if (info == null || info.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {

            updateStuff();

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

To enable this service

```
NetworkEventReceiver monitor = new NetworkEventReceiver(this);
monitor.enable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`NetworkCapabilities`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities) [`hasCapability()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities#hasCapability(int))

So something like this:

```
public boolean hasMobileData() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkCapabilities nc = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(cm.getActiveNetwork());
    return nc.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
}
```

Comment: Is this for wifi or mobile data?

Comment: It works for either. You can use [hasTransport](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities#hasTransport(int)) to determine network type (wifi or mobile).

Answer (score 0):

```
   ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                          activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

Above code will work for you.

**Determine the type of your internet connection**

For Wifi

```
boolean isWiFi = activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
```

For Mobile

You can refer @Chris Stillwell answer.