# In android. Check whether mobile data is on or off

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, telephonymanager

My app need a function to check user's mobile phone has turned on the mobile data or not.

I have referenced this link: [#32239785](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806709/how-to-tell-if-mobile-network-data-is-enabled-or-disabled-even-when-connected/32239785#32239785)

Here is the code provided in that topic

```
boolean mobileYN = false;

TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
if (tm.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY) {
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    {
        mobileYN = Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), "mobile_data", 1) == 1;
    }
    else{
        mobileYN = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), "mobile_data", 1) == 1;
    }
}
```

This code works in most of my mobile phone.

Except on "Nokia 8"(Android 9)

Even I turned off the mobile data. This function still return true.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to check whether the setting for mobile-data is enabled or disabled, or what you really trying to do is check if the device *currently* has mobile-data connection?

If it's the latter case, you should be using `CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE`, example from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing#check-connection):

```
private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "NetworkStatusExample";
...
ConnectivityManager connMgr =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
boolean isWifiConn = false;
boolean isMobileConn = false;
for (Network network : connMgr.getAllNetworks()) {
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(network);
    if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
        isWifiConn |= networkInfo.isConnected();
    }
    if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
        isMobileConn |= networkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Wifi connected: " + isWifiConn);
Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Mobile connected: " + isMobileConn);
```

The above docs link  also has some links to other relevant classes you might want to check out like [`NetworkInfo.DetailedState`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.DetailedState) and [`ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback)

Answer (score 1):

Check with this, if it helps:

```
class InternetNetwork {
companion object {
    fun isOnline(context: Context): Boolean {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            val connectivityManager =
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
            val capabilities =
                connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)
            if (capabilities != null)
                when {
                    capabilities.hasTransport(TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> {
                        Log.i("Internet", "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR")
                        return true
                    }
                    capabilities.hasTransport(TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> {
                        Log.i("Internet", "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI")
                        return true
                    }
                    capabilities.hasTransport(TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> {
                        Log.i("Internet", "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET")
                        return true
                    }
                }
        } else {
            val connectivityManage =
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
            val netInfo = connectivityManage.activeNetworkInfo
            return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected
        }

        return false
    }
}
}
```