# Is there a way to know what app has turned on Mobile Data on Android?

Tags: android

I want to which process has turned on mobitel data so I can create a log history of changes. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806709/how-to-tell-if-mobile-network-data-is-enabled-or-disabled-even-when-connected) but I don't see anything about what made a switch.

Comment: The user turns it on.

Comment: But is there somekind of activity log to track which process activated it?